# PySpark & SQL: Fixing a type error when running a Higher-Order-Function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to run an SQL query on the following PySpark DF:

```
+--------------------+
|              values|
+--------------------+
|[1.09125882, 0.97...|
|[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1...|
|[1.06119951, 1.04...|
|[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1...|
|[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1...|
|[1.0, 1.12954037,...|
|[1.0, 1.08907695,...|
|[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1...|
|[1.017957352, 0.9...|
|[1.015306123, 1.0...|
|[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1...|
|[1.015306123, 1.0...|
|[1.07177033, 1.00...|
|[1.0, 1.09094099,...|
|[1.061907984, 1.0...|
|[1.072550215, 1.0...|
|[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1...|
|[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1...|
|[1.08173935, 1.04...|
|[1.039907582, 1.0...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

I'm referencing the code from [this](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/higher-order-functions.html) DataBricks tutorial (it's the last example). The query is as follows:

```
query = """SELECT values,
         AGGREGATE(values,
           (1.0 AS product, 0 AS N),
           (buffer, value) -> (value * buffer.product, buffer.N + 1),
           buffer -> Power(buffer.product, 1.0 / buffer.N)) geomean FROM df_table"""
data_fin = spark.sql(query)
```

For reference, here's the schema for the DF:

```
root
 |-- values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

And I register the table with:

```
data5.registerTempTable("df_table")
```

However, I'm getting a type error:

```
An error was encountered:
"cannot resolve 'aggregate(df_table.`values`, named_struct('product', 1.0BD, 'N', 0), lambdafunction(named_struct('col1', (namedlambdavariable() * CAST(namedlambdavariable().`product` AS DOUBLE)), 'col2', (namedlambdavariable().`N` + 1)), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable()), lambdafunction(POWER(CAST(namedlambdavariable().`product` AS DOUBLE), CAST((CAST(1.0BD AS DECIMAL(11,1)) / CAST(CAST(namedlambdavariable().`N` AS DECIMAL(10,0)) AS DECIMAL(11,1))) AS DOUBLE)), namedlambdavariable()))' due to data type mismatch: argument 3 requires struct<product:decimal(2,1),N:int> type, however, 'lambdafunction(named_struct('col1', (namedlambdavariable() * CAST(namedlambdavariable().`product` AS DOUBLE)), 'col2', (namedlambdavariable().`N` + 1)), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable())' is of struct<col1:double,col2:int> type.; line 2 pos 9;\nProject [values#514, aggregate(values#514, named_struct(product, 1.0, N, 0), lambdafunction(named_struct(col1, (lambda value#565 * cast(lambda buffer#564.product as double)), col2, (lambda buffer#564.N + 1)), lambda buffer#564, lambda value#565, false), lambdafunction(POWER(cast(lambda buffer#566.product as double), cast(CheckOverflow((promote_precision(cast(1.0 as decimal(11,1))) / promote_precision(cast(cast(lambda buffer#566.N as decimal(10,0)) as decimal(11,1)))), DecimalType(13,12)) as double)), lambda buffer#566, false)) AS geomean#563]\n+- SubqueryAlias `df_table`\n   +- Project [zpid#26, zip_#455, values#514]\n      +- Project [_id#0, address#1, cmaToolCompCandidates#2, comps#3, data#4, description#5, hiResImageLink#6, homeType#7, hugePhotos#8, latitude#9, location#10, longitude#11, nearbyHomes#12, nearbySales#13, no#14, priceHist#15, priceHistory#16, propertyTaxRate#17, rentZestimate#18L, resoFacts#19, responsivePhotos#20, streetViewTileImageUrlMediumAddress#21, taxHistory#22, tourPhotos#23, ... 6 more fields]\n         +- Project [_id#0, address#1, cmaToolCompCandidates#2, comps#3, data#4, description#5, hiResImageLink#6, homeType#7, hugePhotos#8, latitude#9, location#10, longitude#11, nearbyHomes#12, nearbySales#13, no#14, priceHist#15, priceHistory#16, propertyTaxRate#17, rentZestimate#18L, resoFacts#19, responsivePhotos#20, streetViewTileImageUrlMediumAddress#21, taxHistory#22, tourPhotos#23, ... 5 more fields]\n            +- Filter (zip_#455 = 02138)\n               +- Project [_id#0, address#1, cmaToolCompCandidates#2, comps#3, data#4, description#5, hiResImageLink#6, homeType#7, hugePhotos#8, latitude#9, location#10, longitude#11, nearbyHomes#12, nearbySales#13, no#14, priceHist#15, priceHistory#16, propertyTaxRate#17, rentZestimate#18L, resoFacts#19, responsivePhotos#20, streetViewTileImageUrlMediumAddress#21, taxHistory#22, tourPhotos#23, ... 4 more fields]\n                  +- Repartition 40, false\n                     +- Relation[_id#0,address#1,cmaToolCompCandidates#2,comps#3,data#4,description#5,hiResImageLink#6,homeType#7,hugePhotos#8,latitude#9,location#10,longitude#11,nearbyHomes#12,nearbySales#13,no#14,priceHist#15,priceHistory#16,propertyTaxRate#17,rentZestimate#18L,resoFacts#19,responsivePhotos#20,streetViewTileImageUrlMediumAddress#21,taxHistory#22,tourPhotos#23,... 3 more fields] parquet\n"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 767, in sql
    return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'aggregate(df_table.`values`, named_struct('product', 1.0BD, 'N', 0), lambdafunction(named_struct('col1', (namedlambdavariable() * CAST(namedlambdavariable().`product` AS DOUBLE)), 'col2', (namedlambdavariable().`N` + 1)), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable()), lambdafunction(POWER(CAST(namedlambdavariable().`product` AS DOUBLE), CAST((CAST(1.0BD AS DECIMAL(11,1)) / CAST(CAST(namedlambdavariable().`N` AS DECIMAL(10,0)) AS DECIMAL(11,1))) AS DOUBLE)), namedlambdavariable()))' due to data type mismatch: argument 3 requires struct<product:decimal(2,1),N:int> type, however, 'lambdafunction(named_struct('col1', (namedlambdavariable() * CAST(namedlambdavariable().`product` AS DOUBLE)), 'col2', (namedlambdavariable().`N` + 1)), namedlambdavariable(), namedlambdavariable())' is of struct<col1:double,col2:int> type.; line 2 pos 9;\nProject [values#514, aggregate(values#514, named_struct(product, 1.0, N, 0), lambdafunction(named_struct(col1, (lambda value#565 * cast(lambda buffer#564.product as double)), col2, (lambda buffer#564.N + 1)), lambda buffer#564, lambda value#565, false), lambdafunction(POWER(cast(lambda buffer#566.product as double), cast(CheckOverflow((promote_precision(cast(1.0 as decimal(11,1))) / promote_precision(cast(cast(lambda buffer#566.N as decimal(10,0)) as decimal(11,1)))), DecimalType(13,12)) as double)), lambda buffer#566, false)) AS geomean#563]\n+- SubqueryAlias `df_table`\n   +- Project [zpid#26, zip_#455, values#514]\n      +- Project [_id#0, address#1, cmaToolCompCandidates#2, comps#3, data#4, description#5, hiResImageLink#6, homeType#7, hugePhotos#8, latitude#9, location#10, longitude#11, nearbyHomes#12, nearbySales#13, no#14, priceHist#15, priceHistory#16, propertyTaxRate#17, rentZestimate#18L, resoFacts#19, responsivePhotos#20, streetViewTileImageUrlMediumAddress#21, taxHistory#22, tourPhotos#23, ... 6 more fields]\n         +- Project [_id#0, address#1, cmaToolCompCandidates#2, comps#3, data#4, description#5, hiResImageLink#6, homeType#7, hugePhotos#8, latitude#9, location#10, longitude#11, nearbyHomes#12, nearbySales#13, no#14, priceHist#15, priceHistory#16, propertyTaxRate#17, rentZestimate#18L, resoFacts#19, responsivePhotos#20, streetViewTileImageUrlMediumAddress#21, taxHistory#22, tourPhotos#23, ... 5 more fields]\n            +- Filter (zip_#455 = 02138)\n               +- Project [_id#0, address#1, cmaToolCompCandidates#2, comps#3, data#4, description#5, hiResImageLink#6, homeType#7, hugePhotos#8, latitude#9, location#10, longitude#11, nearbyHomes#12, nearbySales#13, no#14, priceHist#15, priceHistory#16, propertyTaxRate#17, rentZestimate#18L, resoFacts#19, responsivePhotos#20, streetViewTileImageUrlMediumAddress#21, taxHistory#22, tourPhotos#23, ... 4 more fields]\n                  +- Repartition 40, false\n                     +- Relation[_id#0,address#1,cmaToolCompCandidates#2,comps#3,data#4,description#5,hiResImageLink#6,homeType#7,hugePhotos#8,latitude#9,location#10,longitude#11,nearbyHomes#12,nearbySales#13,no#14,priceHist#15,priceHistory#16,propertyTaxRate#17,rentZestimate#18L,resoFacts#19,responsivePhotos#20,streetViewTileImageUrlMediumAddress#21,taxHistory#22,tourPhotos#23,... 3 more fields] parquet\n"
```

Is there a way to keep the data types when preparing the SQL query? I'd assume that the schema in the original DF is correct for the SQL query.

Comment: is `data_fin` & `data5` same or different ?

Comment: They're different. `data_fin` is the DF resulting from the transformation of `data5`

Comment: can you show both dataframe printschema ?

Answer (score 3):

When you need to run functions as `AGGREGATE` or `REDUCE` (both are aliases), the first parameter is an array value and the second parameter you must define what are your default values and types. You can write `1.0 (Decimal, Double or Float)`, `0 (Boolean, Byte, Short, Integer or Long)` but this leaves Spark the responsibility to define what could be between those options. In your example is throwing an error because the implicit chose data types are not matching.

To guarantee the data type is correct and your query will always run, change `(1.0 AS product, 0 AS N)` to `(cast(1 as double) AS product, cast(0 as double) AS N)`